# How can I check if elements with a certain ID are clicked?

Tags: javascript

So I have the following divs

```
    <div id="az" class="d_1" value="data1"></div>
    <div id="az" class="d_2" value="data2"></div>
    <div id="by" class="d_3" value="data3"></div>
    <div id="az" class="d_4" value="data4"></div>
```

how can I check **only** if `az` divs are clicked without adding `onClick="reply_click(this)"` to every div?

Comment: Why do you have 3(!) divs with the same ID? This is an invalid HTML

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: I think you need to swap the id and the class and then use document.getElementsByClassName("az"). As was pointed out above, Ids are supposed to be unique (which your classes are)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delegation is what you want after swapping ID and class and using data attributes because IDs need to be unique and DIVs do not have value

```js
window.addEventListener("load",function(){ // on page load
  document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click",function(e) { // clicking anything in container
    const tgt = e.target; // the event target (what was clicked)
    if (tgt.classList.contains("az")) { // ignore click on "by"
      console.log("az clicked", tgt.dataset.value)
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="az" id="d_1" data-value="data1">D1</div>
  <div class="az" id="d_2" data-value="data2">D2</div>
  <div class="by" id="d_3" data-value="data3">D3</div>
  <div class="az" id="d_4" data-value="data4">D4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`id` attribute must always be unique:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

You have your class and id attributes structured the opposite of what they should be.  class can be non-unique to refer to a group of elements.

Below is a sample of how you can use `addEventListener` and the class css selector to achieve what you asked for.

```js
function reply_click(){
  console.log(this.getAttribute('value'));
}

document.getElementsByClassName('az').forEach( el => el.addEventListener('click',reply_click) );
```

```html
    <div class="az" id="d_1" value="data1">1</div>
    <div class="az" id="d_2" value="data2">2</div>
    <div class="by" id="d_3" value="data3">3</div>
    <div class="az" id="d_4" value="data4">4</div>
```

Comment: `[...document.querySelectorAll('.az')].forEach` is easier to read - only IE does not handle `document.querySelectorAll('.az').forEach`

Comment: Also delegation is better

Comment: agreed on the use of Array.from, but how do you plan to express event delegation in a simplistic enough manner for someone who is just learning onclick?

Comment: Mine only has one more addEventListener than yours ;)

Comment: I actually wasn't even entirely sure I should use addEventListener for the example, rather than plain onclick, just because it matches what he's doing more closely.  But right, agree that it is better.